# use messagestore with JSON api

Tags: jms, wso2, esb

I have create an API in WSO2 ESB that receives JSON messages. I have created a messagestore to store these messages in Message Broker (guaranteed delivery pattern). 
Now, the message processor that must read the queue and send the message to the backend REST api, gives the error:

```
    TID: [0] [ESB] [2014-11-21 14:28:46,752] ERROR {org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender} -  Error sending Message to url : http://lnx17.redora.local:28080/MZK-DataServices/ProcessJson/cases/newCase {org.apache.synapse.message.senders.blocking.BlockingMsgSender}
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Payload could not be written as JSON.
```

The endpoint is currently defined as an address endpoint with JSON type. I have also tried a HTTP endpoint.

In Message Broker, I cannot see the message, because it is stored as an Object (?)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Before sending it to the message store, remove the REST_URL_POSTFIX using a property mediator:

```
<property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
```

Then the message will correctly be transferred.

Comment: This does not completely seem to solve the issue: sometimes it comes back? After some restarts, the queue seems to be picked up again - but why it fails is not clear.